# Turning a LED on and off with delay on ARM micro-controller

Tags: c, arm, embedded, microcontroller

I am new to embedded C and been struggling with it for a while now.

The desired output for this project is:

The blue LED should be on initially. When SW1 is not pressed, the blue LED must be kept on. When SW1 is pressed the blue LED should turn on and off every 100ms. (SW1 is negative logic).

I wrote this code but it doesn't seem to be working properly. I tried it on the simulator and the LED toggles but the delay is more than 100ms, it's like a second. And on the real board, I get random results, sometimes it doesn't turn off and sometimes it changes color to purple. Why isn't this code behaving as it should? Why am I getting random results?

**Schematics**

[image]

```
// BranchingFunctionsDelays.c Lab 6
// Runs on LM4F120/TM4C123
// Use simple programming structures in C to
// toggle an LED while a button is pressed and
// turn the LED on when the button is released.  
// This lab will use the hardware already built into the LaunchPad.
// Daniel Valvano, Jonathan Valvano
// January 15, 2016

// built-in connection: PF0 connected to negative logic momentary switch, SW2
// built-in connection: PF1 connected to red LED
// built-in connection: PF2 connected to blue LED
// built-in connection: PF3 connected to green LED
// built-in connection: PF4 connected to negative logic momentary switch, SW1

#include "TExaS.h"

#define GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x400253FC))
#define GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025400))
#define GPIO_PORTF_AFSEL_R      (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025420))
#define GPIO_PORTF_PUR_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025510))
#define GPIO_PORTF_DEN_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x4002551C))
#define GPIO_PORTF_AMSEL_R      (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025528))
#define GPIO_PORTF_PCTL_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x4002552C))
#define SYSCTL_RCGC2_R          (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x400FE108))
#define SYSCTL_RCGC2_GPIOF      0x00000020  // port F Clock Gating Control

// basic functions defined at end of startup.s
void DisableInterrupts(void); // Disable interrupts
void EnableInterrupts(void);  // Enable interrupts
void portF_init(void);
void delay100ms(unsigned long time);


int main(void)
{
        unsigned long volatile delay;
      // activate grader and set system clock to 80 MHz
        TExaS_Init(SW_PIN_PF4, LED_PIN_PF2);  
        portF_init();
        EnableInterrupts();      
        // set PF2
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R |= 0x04;
        while(1)
        {
                delay100ms(1);
              // if switch PF4 is pressed and LED is ON (00000101)
            if( GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R == 0x05)
                {
                      // turn LED OFF (clear bit)
                      GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R &= ~0x04;
                }      
                // if switch PF4 is pressed and LED is OFF (00000001)
                else if (GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R == 0x01)
                {
                        // set PF2 - turn LED ON
                      GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R |= 0x04;
                }
                else
                {
                        // set PF2
                        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R |= 0x04; 
                }
        }
}

void portF_init(void)
{
        volatile unsigned long delay;
        SYSCTL_RCGC2_R |= 0x00000020;     // 1) F clock
        delay = SYSCTL_RCGC2_R;           // delay  
        GPIO_PORTF_AMSEL_R = 0x00;        // 3) disable analog function
        GPIO_PORTF_PCTL_R = 0x00000000;   // 4) GPIO clear bit PCTL  
        GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R = 0x04;          // 5) PF4 input, PF2 output  
        GPIO_PORTF_AFSEL_R = 0x00;        // 6) no alternate function
        GPIO_PORTF_PUR_R = 0x08;          // enable pull-up resistor
        GPIO_PORTF_DEN_R = 0x14;          // 7) enable digital pins PF4 & PF2        
}

void delay100ms(unsigned long time)
{
        unsigned long i;
        while(time > 0)
        {
                i = 1333333;  // this number means 100ms
                while(i > 0)
                {
                        i = i - 1;
                }
                time = time - 1; // decrements every 100 ms
      }
}
```

Comment: As a start in your delay100ms function, change `unsigned long i` to `volatile unsigned long i`, the same for `time`, the compiler could be optomising your function away to nothing.

Comment: Use a hardware timer to make an accurate delay. How do you calculated the values for your software delay? Also your delay function can be interrupted by ISRs, and the ISR execution time will add to the delay.

Comment: You are trying to fix too many problems at once: 1. First do only the simplest program that sets single led. Test all leds and their combinations this way. 2. Then do a program which toggles a led when you press button down. 3. Then do a program that blinks led without any button presses. 4. Then combine those 3 into one program.

Comment: @BenceKaulics This project is a part of an embedded systems online course, we didn't study timers and interrupts yet, but we're going to. The professor wrote this delay function, told us to use it and not to worry about its calculations for now.

Comment: @user694733 Thanks! Will do that now.

Comment: Yes, take baby steps - if you have a load of implementation/code and it doesn't work, you don't know where to start - and there could easily be multiple problems. You should start with the basics, exactly like @user694733 says. so you build slightly more complex stuff on something that works, and debug that stuff before moving on to more complexity

Comment: Use the debugger.  Set a breakpoint in the while loop.  Examine the value of GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R when SW1 is pressed and not pressed.  Step through the code.  What is happening that is different from what you expect/intend?

Comment: @MahmoudKhaled before starting to control LED, did you check the stability of your SW. Be sure that you have a good debounce filter otherwise, you will have a switching frequency higher than 100ms (this is the real world).

Answer (score 0):

I can see there are some mistakes in your program. Lets discuss them one by one.. 
First define two variables which will make your code more readable:

```
#define PF2     0x04
#define PF4     0X10
```

Now, Starting with portF_init. Change these two lines in your code:
1. Our target is to make PF4 bit as input and PF2 as output. So, first thing which we set is direction. **Make note here,** whenever you want to modify any bits of register always use bitwise operator.

```
GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R ¦= 1 << PF2;

GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R  &= ~(1<< PF4);
```

2. When we select any port as input, the port state is unknown. So, to bring it to a known position either we Pull-up, that is make it high or pull down that is making low by default. Here, in our case, switch is active low, so we'll keep the state of port as Pull up by default.
   GPIO_PORTF_PUR_R ¦= 1 << PF4;

I don't know what is the use of 
GPIO_PORTF_DEN_R 
You can comment it for now. Keep rest init part of code as it is.

Now, coming to your execution part, here our target is to read PF4. Now, you are trying to read complete port F instead of just PF4 bit. So, where ever you are trying to read PF4 change the statement to:

```
if (GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R & (1 << PF4) == PF4)  // This statement will only read PF4 bit And tests if PF4 is high
```

Also, when you are trying to turn on led, use:

```
GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ¦= 1<< PF2;
```

Try these suggestion and let us know your findings.

Regards

Comment: Good to know this Khaled.. If my answer helped you, can you please mark it as answer? This will help others as well for referring this post.